# Notification idle yahoo messenger

Tags: yahoo-messenger

Can I receive any kind of notification (e.g., sound notification, tool-tip next to the clock, email, etc.) when someone starts being idle *AND* when it stops being idle? This would really help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a program called [pidgin](https://pidgin.im/).

You can set up sound notifications with it.

It supports Yahoo and other messenger apps as well.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? Do You have any other problem? If it is solved, please accept the solution. If You have any other questions, feel confident to ask.